# What happens to an event and the memory it uses when it's fired an no handler is registered?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

What happens to a Reactor-EventBus event and especially the memory itself and its data payload use when it's fired and there's no handler registered?

Is it going to be disposed? Or will those Event objects be collected in the ringbuffer?

My guess is that it will be disposed, but I'd like to be sure about that.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. The Event object is allocated; zero or more handlers are called; it is released to GC.

Comment: @EJP I'd like to set a green tick, but that's a comment ;)